# Is there a way to run Perl code from inside Excel and have it return a hash?

Tags: perl, excel, return, vba

I am trying to run some Perl code from Excel. If I try to pass something to the script using the shell command I am not able to return a value. I figure that if I am able to run the script in as a com module or something like that I might be able to get back a value, array or hash from the script. Does anyone know if this is possible? and if so How? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious what is your desired result ... I mean do yo *need* to run a Perl script from Excel? Is it possible you could run it outside of Excel and get the same result?

If so, you could export the rows you need to perform whatever functionality the script is to do and then generate another spreadsheet using the following modules:

[CPAN -> Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.58/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm)

[CPAN -> Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm)

Answer (score 0):

In the Perl script, write the desired return value to a temporary output file. In VB, wait until the Perl script process is complete, then open and parse the contents of that file. You could let VB choose the name of the temporary file and hand that name to the Perl script as a command line argument or an environment variable.